# Firebase Ad Performance tile not showing

Tags: firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Mobile Ad Performance feature that is in beta now (it is version 10.2.3). I added the SDK and was able to see using Firebase DebugView that events like `ad_impression` and `ad_click` are collected. However there is no Ad Performance Tile on Firebase Analytics tab.

How can I make it appear there?

Comment: Don't post the same question twice. If you have improvements to make, edit your original question by clicking the edit link under it.

Comment: They are different questions. The problem described here is that Ad Performance Tile not showing (I don't see the entire tile). The second question is that the Ad Performance tile is shown but there are no events on it. These problems are in two different projects